# Adding a record from html form to oracle database

Tags: php, sql, html, oracle

I have a HTML form that I want to add a record to an Oracle database when somebody hits submit. The table is hooking up somewhat, the problem is that when somebody submits their information they come up as NULL values in the database table.

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" action="/Add_File.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"><!--Form-->
<fieldset>
    <label class ="label1" for "name">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="fname"><br />
    <label class ="label1" for "name">Surname: </label><input type="text" name="sname"><br/>
    <label for="email">E-mail Address: </label><input type="text" name="email"><br />
    <label  for "address">Address: </label> <input type="text" name="address"><br />
    <label class="label" for "Password">Select a Password: </label> <input type="password" name="pass"><br />
    <label class="label" for "Password">Retype-Password:</label> <input type="password" name="pass2"><br />
</fieldset>
<fieldset><input class="button" type="submit" onclick="message()" value="Submit"/>
    <input class="button" type="reset" value="reset form" onclick="myFunction()"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
$dbuser = "scott";
$dbpassword = "tiger";
$db = "orabis";
$conn = oci_connect($dbuser,$dbpassword,$db);

if (!$conn){
    echo "Connection error";
    exit;
}

$fname=$_POST['First_Name'];
$sname=$_POST['Surname'];
$email=$_POST['Email_Address'];
$address=$_POST['Address'];
$selpass=$_POST['Select_A_Password'];
$confirm=$_POST['Retype_Password'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Become_A_Member_110385461(First_Name,Surname,Email_Address,Address,Select_A_Password,Retype_Password) 
VALUES ('".$fname."','".$sname."', '".$email."', '".$address."','".$selpass."', '".$confirm."')";

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "Error in preparing the statement";
    exit;
}

oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
print "Record Inserted";
oci_commit($conn);
oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: use [`oci_bind_by_name`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php)

Comment: Thanks Alexander, Im only a beginner tho, would u mind explaining what u mean?

Comment: I provided you with link in my comment. Meanwhile, your current issue should be solved by answer below

Comment: If you want to understand why you need to use `oci_bind_by_name` read about sql injections

Comment: Fantastic stuff lads, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

change like this

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$sname=$_POST['sname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$selpass=$_POST['pass'];
$confirm=$_POST['pass2'];
```